# 'gensim._matutils.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, cython, gensim

I'm trying to import gensim on Jupyter Lab, but it gives me an error as below.
I've tried updating or downgrading related libraries (numpy, cython, gensim) but still no luck. Has anyone had the same issue but solved it?

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py in <module>
      3 """
      4 
----> 5 from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
      6 import logging
      7 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/corpora/__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # bring corpus classes directly into package namespace, to save some typing
----> 6 from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
      7 
      8 from .mmcorpus import MmCorpus  # noqa:F401

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py in <module>
     13 import numpy
     14 
---> 15 from gensim import interfaces, utils
     16 
     17 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/interfaces.py in <module>
     19 import logging
     20 
---> 21 from gensim import utils, matutils
     22 from six.moves import range
     23 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py in <module>
   1102 try:
   1103     # try to load fast, cythonized code if possible
-> 1104     from gensim._matutils import logsumexp, mean_absolute_difference, dirichlet_expectation
   1105 
   1106 except ImportError:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/_matutils.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in init gensim._matutils()

AttributeError: type object 'gensim._matutils.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by upgrading numpy

```
pip install -U numpy
```